# Bypass server memory_limits for Cloud Asset resources

Tags: assets, server, s3

I’m building a site that needs to upload large video files to Amazon S3. We have run into limitations with our host where they will only increase the memory_limit to 512mb and it’s likely that there will be video files in excess of this. It seems that Craft stages the video file on the server before sending it to S3. Is there a way around this so we can bypass the hosting limits on file uploads and memory and not make the user use an FTP client to upload bigger files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything native in Craft that is going to help you here.

FTP is probably the best bet.  Only images get downloaded from external sources during indexing, so it's a simple as FTP'ing up the files and rebuild the asset source indexes (which could be automated via cron job).

Comment: For what it's worth, [anecdotal evidence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5828654) seems to dispute the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) that ``memory_limit`` actually needs to exceed whatever file size you want to upload. Not sure how that affects Craft though since that may affect image processing...